# how to create nested node C#

Tags: c#, .net, json

i have developing json feed using sql database.
i have used below code my project to get a responce

```
public string ConvertDataTabletoString()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString());
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from table4", connection);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            da.Fill(dt);
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new  JavaScriptSerializer();

            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {


               row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
               foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
               {    
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
               }
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            return serializer.Serialize(new { contacts = rows }); 
        }
```

below json format for got a response for above code

```
     {
        "contacts":[
        {
        "username":"raja",
        "empid":"45"
        }
        ]
        }
```

but my requirement is below format
how to add  "employee" inside my json.

```
{
        "contacts":[
        {
        "username":"raja",
        "employee":{
        "empid":"40"
        }
        }
        ]
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proposal:

1. Just after finishing `foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {}` try to
   clone the rows collection into a new one (not a reference)
2. Loop through that newly created collection and modify it to suit your
   needs
3. Serialize the new collection and return it.

Hope that helps,